# Is it possible to reuse a smart pointer's memory for another object?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Let's say I have two unrelated types that are exactly the same size.

```cpp
struct Foo { ... };
struct Bar { ... };
```

And now, let's say that I have a tree of `Foo` that I would like to convert to a tree of `Bar`.

```cpp
template <typename Leaf>
struct Tree
{
    Leaf data;
    std::unique_ptr<Tree> lhs;
    std::unique_ptr<Tree> rhs;
};

Tree<Foo> footree = ...;
Tree<Bar> bartree = convert(std::move(footree)); // <--
```

How could I perform this conversion while reusing the heap-allocated memory of `footree`? In other words, how can I (safely) convert a `Tree<Foo>` to a `Tree<Bar>` with no extra memory allocations?

This is a simplified example of what I'm actually trying to do. In reality `Foo` and `Bar` are recursive variants with differing numbers of alternative types.

Comment: There's no safe way to do this, and based on how you describe your actual `Foo` and `Bar` types, I'd be surprised a solution exists.  At minimum you'll be violating strict aliasing rules.

Comment: `std::variant` may be of use.

Comment: @user202729 Didn't you mean `std::aligned_storage`?

Comment: (ah right, it's possible to release a unique_ptr. Although it's better to add a `static_assert` that the size are equal, or `if constexpr` it to reallocate the memory in the other case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For raw pointers it isn't difficult. One simply needs to trigger destructor of `Foo` manually and apply constructor manually via placement new. The `enable_if` is SFINAE that ensures that sizes and alignment match.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename U, typename V, typename... Args,
         std::enable_if_t<sizeof(U) == sizeof(V) && alignof(U) == alignof(V), int> = 0>
U* repurpose_raw_ptr(V* ptr, Args&&... args)
{
    ptr->~V();
    return new ((void*)ptr) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>* X = new std::vector<int>({1,2,3,4,5});
    std::vector<double>* Y =
        repurpose_raw_ptr<std::vector<double>>(X,
            std::initializer_list<double>{1.,2.,3.,4.,5.});

    std::cout << Y->at(0) << " " << Y->at(4);

    delete Y;

    return 0;
}
```

You can apply the function to "convert" from `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` to `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` by using the `release()` method of unique pointer where it releases ownership of the object. Something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Bar> X = ...;
std::unique_ptr<Foo> Y = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(repurpose_raw_ptr<Bar>(X.release(),...));
```

Here it assumes `delete Foo` and `delete Bar` is same as destruction of Foo/Bar + dealloc of a raw pointer which might not always be the case I believe.

In general, I do not recommend doing something like this as it is hard to ensure that structures have same size/alignment in a cross-platform environment.

Edit: Formerly, missed that you wanted to convert `Foo` to `Bar` in some way. You'll have to temporarily copy/move instance `Foo` elsewhere and then trigger trigger the memory repurposing.

Comment: Regarding the comment about cross-platform, this can be somewhat protected against by using `static_assert` to check both size and alignments (with `sizeof` and `alignof`).  This at least results in a compiler error, instead of hiding weird behavior.

Comment: @ALX23z Thank you, this works perfectly! Is there anything I should watch out for with this solution? For example, would it be safe to call `repurpose_raw_ptr` on the address of an object with a non-trivial destructor and automatic storage duration?

Comment: @jinscie123 yes, it is safe to call on objects with non-trivial destructors. Here, `ptr->~V()` calls the destructor of the object. Just make sure that the `ptr` at no point afterwards is used as the former type.