# C++ Extend Smart pointers so that they can also be used for substitution

Tags: c++, stdvector, smart-pointers, visitor-pattern

I have been writing a pet programming language using c++. I've mostly settled on using a [Visitor Design Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor) to interreact with my AST. The interactions I'll need is some codegen, and various ways of printing the AST to text files, for debugging mostly.

I also want the Visitor pattern to be able to manipulate the structure of the AST, this means replacing nodes with other nodes. So I'd have a setup like this:
`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes = [A, B, C];`
After the Visitor runs through the tree, it will produce a list of substitutions, something like "Replace B with D"

I then want to perform these substitutions, ideally without re-walking the entire tree.

I thought this should be trivial since I'm using the smart pointers anyway, they could serve as a layer of redirection, so if the substitutions were a list of references to the smart pointers I could then update the smart pointer to point at the new object.

Something like this:
  before substitution `[ptrA -> A, ptrB -> B, ptrC -> C]`
  after substitution   `[ptrA -> A, ptrB -> D, ptrC -> C]`
If I were using raw pointers instead of smart pointers this would indeed be trivial.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65803083/is-it-possible-to-reuse-a-smart-pointers-memory-for-another-object) it seems that this is not really supported/recommended by the C++ Standard library smart pointers. I'm wondering if I should try to extend/replace the smart pointers with my own implementation that includes this functionality. Or perhaps there is some other standard way to achieve this behavior.

Maybe I use a reference/raw pointer to the shared pointer? That seems awkward since the Visitor pattern would then need these pointer references, probably as an additional argument. I had hoped to do this by simply passing `std::shared_ptr<Node>` through the Visitor pattern. I suppose using `std::shared_ptr<Node>*` instead isn't a big change, so when substituting I replace both the smart pointer and the object, but I'm also not totally sure it's safe to replace the smart pointer by reference which is actually located within the `std::vector`.
That means I probably actually need to store my data like this:
`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>*> nodes;`
But that doesn't seem right to me either since it's a vector of pointers to smart pointers to the Nodes. It's not going to be very efficient to walk the tree with that double indirection for every Node.

(*Note* I know a std::vector is not a Tree, some of the Nodes will contain others Nodes, possibly in std::vectors of their own)

Comment: Are you asking how to make a map<shared_ptr<Node>, shared_ptr<Node>> ?

Comment: Why would you say that it's trivial to replace a raw pointer, but not a smart pointer? It's _more_ trivial to replace a smart pointer, because the lifetime of the contained pointer is properly managed. It's trivial for both or neither. It seems like an unusual design to need _references_ to a smart pointer, but you can store references in a container with `std::reference_wrapper`. Of course, _then_ you must be careful to correctly manage the lifetime of the reference. At least consider using typedef or a struct to give you flexibility to switch out the types later as your code evolves.

Comment: @user253751 a map might be a good way to store my list of substitutions, but that dosen't help me perform the substitutions.

Comment: @paddy If I'm using raw pointers I can overright them to point at a new object. This is trivial because I'm personally taking responsibility for the life cycle of both the old object and the new one. What I'm wishing for is a way to do this with a smart pointer, so the smart pointer is no longer managing the old object since it's pointing elsewhere.

Comment: I just found this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/swap I glossed over this the first couple of times, but I think it's basically exactly what I wanted.

Comment: It's still trivial with smart pointers. The way to do it is the same as with raw pointers. The only thing to watch out for is that when you "rewire" a pointer, you don't lose the last reference to its old value. So normally a remapping operation would store all the pointers being replaced, and then release those after all replacements are made. Then, any pointers whose reference count drops to zero is automatically freed. But if you think about it, then even with raw pointers you need to do the same thing because you must hold a copy of the pointer _somewhere_.

Comment: @ZacharyVanderKlippe what's wrong with old pointer = new pointer; ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use some container holding your Nodes to exchange the pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Node 
{
    virtual ~Node() 
    {
        std::cout << "Node dtor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct A : Node 
{
    virtual ~A() 
    {
        std::cout << "A dtor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : Node 
{
    virtual ~B() 
    {
        std::cout << "B dtor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Container
{
    std::shared_ptr<Node> mNode;    

    virtual ~Container() 
    {
        std::cout << "Container dtor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Container>> nodes;
    std::shared_ptr<Container> c{new Container()};
    c->mNode = std::shared_ptr<Node>(new A());
    nodes.push_back(c);

    std::cout << "A is going to be deleted" << std::endl;

    nodes[0]->mNode = std::shared_ptr<Node>(new B());

    std::cout << "B is going to be deleted" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A is going to be deleted
A dtor called
Node dtor called
B is going to be deleted
Container dtor called
B dtor called
Node dtor called
```

Comment: This is probably a better approach then using the Raw pointers as I mentioned, since all the memory is properly managed. However it still has the double layer of redirection which I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Maybe I could modify your example to skip the one layer of redirection and put the container directly into the vector like this `std::vector<Container> nodes;`  That would make it easy to update the Container without messing with the vector, and I don't have to dereference two pointers when walking the tree. I'll try that.